# Prove $\mathbb Z/4k\mathbb Z^\times$ is acyclic for $k \ge 2$

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

I tried proving it by showing that for every element $a$ the statement $a^{\phi(4k)/2} \equiv 1 \pmod{4k}$ is true by either induction, which did not get me anywhere.

Comment: Every quotient of a cyclic group is cyclic. Unless by "acyclic" you mean something else?

Comment: By definition, $\Bbb Z/(n\Bbb Z)$ is cyclic.

Comment: Are you perhaps talking about the multiplicative group of units in $\mathbb Z_{4k}$, often denoted $\mathbb Z_{4k}^\times$ or $\mathbb Z_{4k}^*$. or $\mathbb Z/4k\mathbb Z^\times$.

Comment: @amWhy Yes thank you.

Comment: It's true for every $n$.  You need to specify that you are talking about the group of units.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean for every element $a$ *relatively prime to $4k$*?

Comment: Note that $a^2\equiv1\bmod 4k $ for $a=\pm 1$ and for $a=2k\pm1$

Comment: I think that for most mathematicians, the word “acyclic” means something quite other than what you clearly meant. Almost certainly, they would prefer “not cyclic”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a cyclic group, at most one element has order $2$,

but, in $(\mathbb Z/4k\mathbb Z)^\times$ for $k\ge2$, both $2k+1$ and $2k-1$ have order $2$.

(You should check that.)

Comment: This makes sense but is there maybe a more elementary explanation if we have not learned this fact yet?

Comment: I find it hard to imagine anything more elementary than this!